# Whats the difference of using ={}() with a lazy property or just =

Tags: swift, properties, lazy-initialization

There are two different ways of using the `lazy property` syntax and I fail to see the difference between them:

```
//1
lazy var a = { "hello" }()

//2
lazy var b = "hello"
```

In other words, why would or wouldn't you use `{}()`
Is there a difference between them or is it just different looks for doing the same thing?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/52824400/1187415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't much difference. `lazy` doesn't care whether you initialise the property with a closure or not. `lazy` just makes the property lazily initialised, i.e. the initialisation expression (the part after the `=`) is evaluated on the first access of the property. That expression can be anything: a string literal, or an immediately-invoked closure, or whatever you like.

So the difference here is just the difference between evaluating `"foo"` and `{ "foo" }()`. The former is just a string literal, whereas the latter invokes a closure, and that closure returns the same string. So it's a tiny bit of overhead, that will totally be optimised away if you use `-O`. Using [Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org), you can verify that the assembly output are the same when using `-O`: [String literal](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:swift,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:4),source:%27//+Type+your+code+here,+or+load+an+example.%0Aclass+Foo+%7B%0A++++lazy+var+foo+%3D+%22foo%22%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Swift+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:swift57,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:swift,libs:!(),options:%27-O%27,selection:(endColumn:18,endLineNumber:181,positionColumn:18,positionLineNumber:181,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+swiftc+5.7+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) | [Closure](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:swift,selection:(endColumn:31,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:31,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:31,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:31,startLineNumber:3),source:%27//+Type+your+code+here,+or+load+an+example.%0Aclass+Foo+%7B%0A++++lazy+var+foo+%3D+%7B+%22foo%22+%7D()%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Swift+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:swift57,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:swift,libs:!(),options:%27-O%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+swiftc+5.7+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference when you need to modify a value after creating it. For example:

```
lazy var dateFormatter = {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd" // We can modify the value before setting it
    return df
}()
```